# Kripke structure

Tags: algorithm, logic, automata, temporal, model-checking

What is a (pseudocode) algorithm for checking invariant over Kripke structures, such that in case the invariant is violated, the counterexample returned by the algorithm is of minimal length?

Comment: How is your kripke structure represented? Is it an explicit graph? A BDD? A set of CNF formulas? Each of these will have a different answer.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_structure_(model_checking)

Comment: I am familiar with a Kripke Structure, but though the structure is abstracted as a graph - it seldom is implemented this way in practice. It is usually implemented as a BDD or even more common a a set of CNF formulas.

Comment: Do you know how can I determine time complexity of DSP over a Kripke structure to detected whether a temporal property f is violated :/ in terms  of size M (number of states in the state space) and of f(number of atomic proposition used in the formula)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not provide sufficient detail in the question, but if I had to guess, I would say you are looking for [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Comment: Yes but how can I get minimal length with breadth-first search :/?

Comment: You have not even told us how you measure length, so how could we answer?

Comment: If you're talking about what I think you're talking about (a counter-example is a path in a certain graph) then the answer is: breadth-first search always finds a path to solution which is of minimal length, by design.